# android - Issues in twitter integration using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am newbie to twitter integration in android. I integrated twitter in android app using this [tutorial.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) Here i faced some problems.

1. My App is only executed from ICS if i removed the targetversion from the manifeast. Why?

< uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Here i removed the android:targetSdkVersion="15" from manifeast file.

Now,
< uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" />

2.In the developer console of the twitter, i set the callback url of my app is "https://www.google.co.in/" and then i am trying to run this app using this callback url in our code. Actually after successful signin, it should redirects to the app but here it will redirects to the callback url(means here google console).

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "https://www.google.co.in/";

But here i set the following callback url in our code then it's working fine. Why? is it the default callback url in twitter4j. Please can anyone help me.

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";

**Manifeast file**

```
< manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.twitterconnect"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Permission - Internet Connect -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

< /manifest>
```

Comment: How is your Manifest defined? Specifically for the Activity that handles the authorization.

Comment: @IceMAN: I updated the post with manifeast file code. Please refer this.

Comment: Why do you need to remove  android:targetSdkVersion from Manifest?

Comment: @rineez: Previously i put the long running operations in UI thread so i removed the android:targetSdkVersion. otherwise it will not executed. Now i fixed that problem. it's not required to remove the android:targetSdkVersion instead of this we put the code which is taking some time in the thread/asynctask.

Comment: @naresh Glad that you found the right path at last. There is an obvious reason for keeping long running operations off the UI thread. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting to callback URL after authentication is the normal behavior.  Please read a bit about [OAuth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) first. Call back URL is used to pass authorization token back to the requesting application. You should assign this to a url inside your application which can read the token and take necessary actions using that. In case of twitter4j, the URL `oauth://t4jsample` is able to handle this part. Hope this is clear to you.

Comment: For every twitter integration in android using twitter4j, callback url is "oauth://t4jsample" even if we set the different callback url in the twitter dev console. is it right?

Comment: I download the twitter4j library from http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download(twitter4j-3.0.3.zip (JavaDoc / Migration guide from 2.1.x to 2.2.x)).I used the "twitter4j-core-3.0.3" jar file from this path "twitter4j-3.0.3\lib\". Is it right?

Comment: Is it possible to open the twitter app instead of webpage for authentication?

Comment: @naresh Yes. When using twitter4j you should always use that Callback URL. I don't know about any other ways.
And I'm not sure about possibility of using twitter app instead of the webpage.

Comment: @rineez-What if we are using twitter in different activities of our app and we need to distinguish the callback url for every activity as it should not mix up between activities..??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid Are you using twitter4j? or trying to develop your own twitter integration?

Comment: @rineez-I am using Twitter4j and i found the answer that it can be done using "oauth://t4jxyz" as callback url..thanks for taking an interest in my question !

Comment: My pleasure. So, that means twitter4j just looks for the pattern "oauth://t4j*" in callback URL? 
Please do let me know if that really worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

New Twiiter integration v 1.1

Check code here

https://github.com/dwivedi/twitter_api_1.1_implementation.git

Comment: This uses the same redirect URL "oauth://t4jsample" and it just comes up with an error for me and doesn't redirect me back to my app.